# About Google Map MarkerShape Option of complex shape with v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I create a marker in google map with svg, but the shape is complex.the image map region definition used for drag/click is a rect not drip,(you can try it in the code), so what's the option of MarkerShape?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Complex icons</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

 var myMarker = {
    path: 'M30.6,15.737c0-8.075-6.55-14.6-14.6-14.6c-8.075,0-14.601,6.55-14.601,14.6c0,4.149,1.726,7.875,4.5,10.524c1.8,1.801,4.175,4.301,5.025,5.625c1.75,2.726,5,11.976,5,11.976s3.325-9.25,5.1-11.976c0.825-1.274,3.05-3.6,4.825-5.399C28.774,23.813,30.6,20.012,30.6,15.737z',
    fillColor: 'yellow',
    fillOpacity: 0.8,
    scale: 1
  };
 
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
  draggable:true,
    icon: myMarker
    //,shape:????????????????????
  });
}
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there something wrong with setting the scale less than 1?

e.g. (scale: 0.2,)

Sorry about misunderstanding the question!
The real answer for the shape is that you should replicate the approximate shape with coordinates.
I had no time to produce the exact shape coordinates, but for the 'circle part' of the marker is something like this:

```
var shape = {
    coords: [60,60,60],
    type: 'circle'
};
```

This is an approximate poly for the marker shape:

```
var shape = {
    coords: [60,0, 90,15, 120,60, 90,120, 60, 180, 30,120, 0,60, 30,15, 60,0],
    type: 'poly'
};
```

But if you want to be more precise, you should give more detailed coords.
Finally add the shape to the marker:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    draggable:true,
    icon: myMarker,
    shape: shape
});
```

I hope finally this will help!

Comment: I made it on purpose ,in order to  magnify  the image map region definition used for drag/click,Pay attention to my problems of MarkerShape

Comment: Sorry about misunderstanding the question! I edited my answer.

Comment: this idea is cool, but it is realy fussy, is there a tool or algorithms to get the coords easily